# Linux pipe, fork and execlp: how to get the value written into stream 1

Tags: c++, c, linux, fork, pipe

I use a function (L) to execute another program (K) through `execlp()`.
In the K program, the result is written into stream 1:

```
write(1, (char *)&o, sizeof(int));
```

Since after `execlp()`, the remaining part of L won't be executed, how could I get the result written in stream 1?

Don't ask me why I need to do it this way. It's the requirement for a project.

I followed your guys advices, but now the problem is, the way the K program get the arguments are from streams(one standard stream, one other stream), I'm using pipes to write arguments into corresponding streams (it's done by the parent).

After the child exec, in the parent part, I read from stream 0 (the K program writes its result back in stream 1). But what I could get is what the parent wrote into the stream, not what the K program write back. 
What's wrong? Do I need to add another pipe?

Thanks!!

Comment: You create the pipe; you fork; the child sorts out its plumbing (connects the pipes to the right places and closes the file descriptors) and execs K; the parent sorts out its plumbing (closes enough file descriptors) and reads the response from K.

Comment: There is a book on Linux programming. I suggest you get it

Comment: @staticx: only one book?  Which would you suggest?  Perhaps [The Linux Programming Interface Handbook](http://www.amazon.com/The-Linux-Programming-Interface-Handbook/dp/1593272200)?  Or Stevens [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Environment-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Computing/dp/0321637739)? Or ...

Comment: @Jonathan: http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0789722151?pc_redir=1398818101&robot_redir=1

Comment: [staticx](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2591612/staticx) suggests [Linux Programming By Example](http://www.amazon.com/Linux-Programming-Example-By/dp/0789722151/), dated 1999. I've not read it. It is well reviewed on Amazon. My only concern is the date, but the fundamentals haven't changed much. (The LPI book is from 2010; Stevens is from 2013.)

Comment: Here is another one http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0672320215?pc_redir=1398812418&robot_redir=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key insight, which Jonathan Leffler mentioned in his comment, is that you need to `fork` the program which is running `L` before you call `execlp()`.

After the fork, the parent continues to execute the rest of `L`, and the child morphs into the program `K` by calling `execlp()`, which should never return unless there is an error.

Thus, the assertion that "the remaining part of L won't be executed" is incorrect. It *will* get executed, in the parent process if you write the function `L` correctly.

**Update**: Since the OP made his question more specific, I am appending to this answer.

If you want to retrieve what the child process wrote to `stdout` (fd 1), you need to create a new pipe before the fork, and copy the writing end of this pipe into the child's `stdout`.

Here is an example program, slightly modified from the [pipe man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html).

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pipefd[2];
    pid_t cpid;
    char buf;

    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (cpid == 0) {    /* Child writes into the pipe */
        close(pipefd[0]);          /* Close unused read end */

        // Copy the writing end of the pipe into STDOUT for the child.
        dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

        // Execute your program L here, and its stdout will be captured by the pipe.
        const char* message = "Child is speaking to stdout!";
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, message, strlen(message));
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);


        close(pipefd[1]);
        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    } else {            /* Parent reads child's stdout  from the pipe */
        close(pipefd[1]);          /* Close unused write end */

        // Here the parent process is reading the child's stdout.
        while (read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0)
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);
        wait(NULL);                /* Wait for child */
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!! A new problem has occur though :/ The function works fine, but I'm calling it from main. After it return to main, the cout in main won't work any more. I tried to back up cout before calling and then restore it after, like this(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdbuf/), but it still won't work. cerr will work though. Thank you so much!

Comment: @fuiiii, Please ask a new question for an unrelated issue.
If this answer addresses your original question, please mark it as the accepted answer.